# Adding custom field from a WooCommerce order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a custom field to an output. I know that I can query for an order ID with the code below,

```
    $order_data = array(
        'order_id'             => $order->id,
```

but how do I get a numeric custom field from a specified order? In this case called `wspup_pickup_point_id`. I've tried multiple variations, and I cant find any documentation on it.

Comment: I've tried `$order->wspup_pickup_point_id,` but I dont get any value returned from that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is posted below, whereas `wspup_pickup_point_id` should be replaced with the name of your custom field.

`get_post_meta( $order_id, 'wspup_pickup_point_id', true ),`